# Table view cell to another view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a small app with StoryBoard, that currently consist of a Navigation Controller, Table View Controller and a regular view controller. I have an array of objects that is connected to the table view, and now I want to select one of the objects and get the regular view controller on the screen. So, in StoryBoard I CTRL-drag from the prototype to the view controller in order to create a segue (push). Now, I want it to work, but literally nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this work directly or am I missing to set some options? I really want this to work with the StoryBoard but I tested to give the segue an identifier and implement the below metod, but that didn't work either.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showInfo" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Move `performSegueWithIdentifier:` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method of `UITableView`

Comment: You should really invest some time into searching your answer in already answered questions. There is like 1 billion similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are using the method `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, where it should be `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Don't worry, that's something I keep doing from time to time.

Then, make sure your segue's identifier is "showInfo" in your storyboard and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

for navigating from UITableViewCell, You need to write your "code for navigation" in UITABLEVIEWDELEGATE method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// your code for navigation.

}
```